# Primefaces outputpanel Loaded after page load deffered=true

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I refer  in this link: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/outputPanel.xhtml

In outputpanel page load left-top-corner loader will be shown. I want to know change position that loader has to be possible because avoid to my ajaxstatus loader.When I try or refresh page each time load outputpanel loader and my ajaxstatus loader it will unnecessary to shown.I try below code:

```
<p:outputPanel deferred="true">
........... 
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is, could you rephrase it?

Comment: My question deffered=true to loader(default Progressbar) show in left top corner it will possible to show in center position